# How to do phone call validation using Sinch?

Tags: java, android

I am validating the user phone number using phone call validation. I need to know that what uniqueness Sinch is providing in phone numbers, because i need to add a code for that uniqueness. 
I made a broadcast receiver which receives the incoming calls. I need to validate the call coming from Sinch and verify the user.

My question is that in case any other call comes, broadcast receiver will receive that call also and do the later process which is wrong. Please provide any solution.